# SAGA, GRASS Raster values to null

Tags: qgis, saga, raster-calculator, sextante

I want to make the cells which values "1" to null in QGIS with Grass or Saga tools (exactly Saga).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Volker Wichmann from SAGA GIS forums. If you want to change the cell values to null you can use Saga reclassify grid values from Sextante. Enter the -99999 which will be null on the option for **new values for other values**. Saga accepts -99999 value as NoData.

Answer (score 1):

In GRASS GIS (hence, in QGIS via [GRASS toolbox](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_QGIS) or [Sextante-GRASS plugin](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Sextante)), use [r.null](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.null.html) to set selected values to NULL. Any cell value may be turned into NULL.

Comment: Old, but for anyone else who runs into this, r.null is [not yet running on Sextante](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6893).